# Issue renaming Seurat 4 Object Assays in R: duplicate key fail

Tags: r, object, key, rename, seurat

I am working with spatial transcriptomics data in a Seurat object, on Seurat 4 and the RenameAssays function seems to be glitching.
My object has 2 assays with the following keys:

> Assays(ecf1)
> [1] "DBiTseq2.0" "SCT"

> Key(ecf1)
> DBiTseq2.0          SCT
> "dbitseq20_"       "sct_"

I would like to change assay "DBiTseq2.0" into "RNA", but I get this warning and it does not actually change the name:

> RenameAssays(ecf1, DBiTseq2.0 = "RNA")
> Renaming default assay from DBiTseq2.0 to RNA
> An object of class Seurat
> 34239 features across 2420 samples within 2 assays
> Active assay: RNA (20044 features, 0 variable features)
> 1 other assay present: SCT
> Warning message:
> **Cannot add objects with duplicate keys (offending key: dbitseq20_) setting key to original value 'rna_'**

I have tried to change the key to anything else to avoid that, using:
Key(ecf1[["DBiTseq2.0"]]) <- "newkey_"

But it does not change the issue. The warning is the same, but with the new key.
Other workarounds to load the data into a new assay with FetchData and replacing the dataset did not work either.
I have asked chatGPT, checked forums and the help for each function, but found no viable solution.

Any help would be appreciated, as my last resource is to restart creating the seurat object, and reprocessing the all the data (would prefer not to).

Thanks!